# Linux bash find and delete older than

Tags: file, centos, find

I'm using this command to find and delete all files with same name in current directory and all its subfolders:

```
find . -name backupname.tar.gz -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Now I want to find and delete all files with same name but keep newest one.
I need it to keep newest backup of my sites and delete all old backups
How can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Define what means old backups... I assume they have different names

Comment: I have a server with some sites. The server takes backup of all sites every 3 days and saves them in folders
I need a code to keep only newest backup created from a site and delete all old backups automatically

Comment: Well it's not clear what you mean to be honest but then you can do something like this:

```find /path/to/backups -type f -mtime +1 -print``` - this will print all files older than 1 day. If that's what you need you can add -delete after -print to the above command